# Rails action cable specific consumer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm struggling with **action cable**. In my case I have couple of users (via `Devise`) who can share tasks with each other.

Now when `user#1` share task (via Form) with `user#2` all authenticated users receive notifications.

How and where should I identify my `user#2` to broadcast only to him?

Here is my code so far:

**connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.id
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**cable.js**

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

**todo_channel.rb**

```
class TodoChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "todo_channel_#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end


  def notify
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "todo_channel_#{current_user.id}", message: 'some message'(not implemented yet)
  end
end
```

**todo.coffee**

```
App.todo = App.cable.subscriptions.create "TodoChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    console.log(data['message'])

  notify: ->
    @perform 'notify'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with a different approach. I'll write it here in case someone will find it helpful.

Notification has an id of a user that has to be notified. So in model I have:

```
after_commit :broadcast_notification, on: :create

def broadcast_notification
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "todo_channel_#{self.user_id}", message: 'some message'
end
```

As I placed broadcasting into the model my `todo_channel.rb` looks like this:

```
class TodoChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "todo_channel_#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Comment: This `todo_channel.rb` code only works if you have `app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb` set up to supply the `current_user`. This, and in fact a whole example including security, [is given here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#examples)

Answer (score 9):

i've faced something similar before until i realized that you can actually call  `stream_from` multiple times in the channel and that user will be subscribed to multiple different "rooms" within the same channel connection. Which means you can basically do this

```
class TodoChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "todo_channel_all"                            
    stream_from "todo_channel_#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def notify(data)
    # depending on data given from the user, send it to only one specific user or everyone listening to the "todo_channel_all"
    if data['message']['other_user_id']
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "todo_channel_#{data['message']['other_user_id']}", message: 'some message'
    else
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "todo_channel_all", message: 'some message'
    end

  end
end
```

that code assuming that the user already knows the other user's id and sent it to the channel, you would probably have to wrap that with some security or something, i admit i'm not very well experienced with rails as i'm still learning.

Something else that might be beneficial to you in the future is the fact that you can also broadcast several messages/times in the same channel function. That means you can potentially support sending out your tasks to a single specific user, a list of specific users or everyone. Just iterate on the list/array/whatever of users and broadcast the task/message/notification/whatever to them each on their personal "todo_channel_#{user.id}"

Answer (score 1):

Step#1:    Let each user have unique session token. While subscription, each user will send session token in headers and header is accessible in connection class. Find user by using session token.

Step#2:   Stream user on user id.

Step#3:   While sharing task, take user id too in the request and broadcast on given user id.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "private chat". If you really want to get `current_user.id` you could do it in 3 ways:

1. Some AJAX `onload` call from `todo.coffee` to server.
2. Render `current_user.id` as an attribute in Rails HTML view and then get it via jQuery inside `todo.coffee` (as in https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/ )
3. Create a plain cookie while a user logging in and then check it inside `todo.coffee`

But you shouldn't use `current_user.id` because it's not secure. If you use it then someone might register in the same site and easily listen to other users' private chats by simply providing a random `user_id`.

Instead use the signed (e.g. Rails-encrypted) cookie as a user's unique broadcast identifier. That way if you register in the same site you would never know some other user's signed cookie - so you can't break into an alien private chat.

**app/config/initializers/warden_hooks.rb**

See https://rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.delete("#{scope}.id")
end
```

**todo_channel.rb**

```
class TodoChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "todo_channel_#{params['user_signed_cookie']}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end


  def notify(param_message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "todo_channel_#{param_message['user_signed_cookie']}", message: 'some message'(not implemented yet)
  end
end
```

**todo.coffee**

```
user_signed_cookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)user.id\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

user_logged_in = if user_signed_cookie then true else false

if user_logged_in #avoid repetitive HTTP->WebSockets upgrade pointless browser attempts when no user logged in.
 App.todo = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
          channel:"TodoChannel"
          user_signed_cookie: user_signed_cookie
        },
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    console.log(data['message'])

  notify: (name, content, _) -> #name, content - message fields
    @perform 'notify', name: name, content: content, user_signed_cookie: user_signed_cookie
```